# Does the Sky Stalker Ranger lose Favored Terrain for Level 2 or not?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, ranger, archetype

In the [Ranger Archetype Table](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/Core-classes/Ranger/#Archetypes_Alternate_Class_Features)on the d20 site, it shows that a Sky Stalker ranger loses Level 2 Favored Terrain. On the [Sky Stalker](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo-ranger-archetypes/sky-stalker) class page it does not state that it does, however it does state that the Level 2 Ranger Combat Style list adds the Monstrous Mount feat.

Does the Sky Stalker actually lose Favored Terrain for Level 2, or is this a typo on the site?

Answer (score 5):

#### According to the printed rules, the Sky Stalker* archetype does not lose the Favored Terrain feature.

The [Sky Stalker](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo-ranger-archetypes/sky-stalker) archetype on d20PFSRD does not exist in any of the books. Instead it was printed as "Sable Company Marine" in *Inner Sea Combat* (2014), and the corresponding entry on [Archives of Nethys](https://aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Ranger%20Sable%20Company%20Marine) has the correct name. The text is otherwise the same; the archetype features do not mention losing the Favored Terrain feature. Thus the ranger doesn't lose it by taking this archetype.

Note: The table on d20PFSRD may be accounting for a [2010 Paizo blog post](https://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo5lbqy?Golarion-Day-Return-of-the-Sable-Company), which first introduced the Sable Company Marine. In this original version, the archetype did lose Favored Terrain. However, developer blogs are not the same as printed rulebooks, and the archetype is written differently in *Inner Sea Combat*, which was printed 4 years later. This has not been addressed by errata.

So we can assume that the Sky Stalker / Sable Company Marine does not lose Favored Terrain.

Answer (score 4):

## Trust the archetype page over the table.

The table exists only for convenience. It is compiled from the archetype page, not the other way around. So if there is any discrepancy, the table is probably mistaken.

The Sky Stalker doesn't lose Favored Terrain unless the archetype page says so.

Comment: Might be worth saying why trust one over the other. (I know why, but common knowledge is just common, not universal.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Sure, why in heck not!